# How can i save a video to the camera roll with a specific date?

Tags: swift, phphotolibrary

**I save the video to the end of the camera roll**

```
PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
    PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: mergedVideoFile!)
}) { saved, error in
     if saved {
         print("saved")
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite easy, you need to pass the `Date` while daving the `PHAsset`.

```
PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
    let changeRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: videoUrl)
    changeRequest.creationDate = Date() //Pass whichever Date you want
}) { (success, error) in
    debugPrint(success)
    debugPrint(error)
}
```